# Trying to edit button in a Javascript Todo List

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a todo list in vanilla Javascript with following features:

1. Add todo item to the list
2. Delete todo item by clicking trash icon in the li element (done)
3. Edit the respective todo item by clicking the edit icon (which I am unable to achieve)
4. Strike-through the completed todo item by clicking the checkbox

I am trying to add the edit function, please help me with that:

```js
/*When user enter text in input field and click submit, an item should be added to the list
1. User enter text and click submit
2. When submit clicked, an item added to the list
3. When user click edit icon so, the list item is selected
4. Selected text should be editable
*/


const items = document.querySelectorAll('#list li');
const todoTextInput = document.getElementById('todoTextInput'); 
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit_todo');

const tabs = [];
// const liIndex;

//Add todo to the list
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const todoText = document.getElementById('todoTextInput').value;
    const todoList = document.getElementById('list');
    const todoItem = document.createElement('li');
    todoItem.classList.add('list-group-item', 'd-flex', 'justify-content-between');
    todoItem.innerHTML = `
                            <span>${todoText}</span>
                            <span>
                                <a class="editBtn"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <a class="deleteBtn"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </span>
                                    `;

    todoList.appendChild(todoItem);
    tabs.push(todoText);

    //Clearing input box
    todoTextInput.value = '';
    
    const editBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('editBtn');
    
    // Selecting item by clicking edit button
    for (let i = 0; i < editBtn.length; i++) {
        editBtn[i].addEventListener('click', editItem);
    }
        
    const deleteBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('deleteBtn');
    
    //Selecting item by clicking delete button
    for (let i = 0; i < deleteBtn.length; i++) {
        deleteBtn[i].addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
    };

});


//Deleting selected item
function deleteItem() {
    console.log("Deleted")
    this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}


//Editing selected item
function editItem() {
    const todoTextVal = this.parentNode.parentNode.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
    const liIndex = tabs.indexOf(todoTextVal);
    todoTextInput.value = todoTextVal;
    console.log(todoTextVal + "Index -"+ liIndex);
    
    tabs[liIndex].innerHTML = todoTextInput.value;

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        tabs.push(items[i].innerHTML);
        
    };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css"
        integrity="sha512-5A8nwdMOWrSz20fDsjczgUidUBR8liPYU+WymTZP1lmY9G6Oc7HlZv156XqnsgNUzTyMefFTcsFH/tnJE/+xBg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="./todo.js" defer></script>

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="todoTextInput" id="todoTextInput" class="form-control">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success m-2" id="submit_todo">Add Todo</button>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group" id="list">
            <!-- <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
                <span>Apple</span>
                <span>
                    <a class="editBtn"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a class="deleteBtn"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
                <span>Mango</span>
                <span>
                    <a class="editBtn"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a class="deleteBtn"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </span>
            </li> -->
        </ul>
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using google firebase > Firestore
You can just use that with vanilla javascript in your website. With that you can make a small database where you can read data from or write data to so everything saves!

You can take a look on the google firestore docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore).